# How to get specific column's data in ui-grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

There is a column which is percentile data in ui-grid, I want to calculate it at footer. It seems like ui-grid doesn't support this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give more details on what you have and what you have tried so far?

Comment: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/oe2sRIqvYRmWDiniqXdP?p=preview)      I used page in ui-grid, now i just want to get specific column's data at page one not the whole column's data. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregations should take account of pagination, so if you set an aggregation on the column it should aggregate only the currently visible values.